# What Property Governs The Text Color Of Checkbox Text OnMouseOver In Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Because the color of the background image in my application is very dark, and the Alpha is very low, when I hover my mouse over a checkbox, the text is scarcely visible.  I've scoured the interwebz in vain for what property to set, either at design-time or in the MouseOver event for the checkbox and just can't figure out what property or setStyle property to alter to be able to control the color of the checkbox text when the mouse pointer is hovering over it.  Does anyone have any experience in this area, who could point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [`textRollOverColor`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Button.html#style:textRollOverColor)?

The [Flex style explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html) is a good resource for this sort of thing.  See the "Form Elements" category for checkboxes.